# How to UPDATE the same table which you use in the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
UPDATE recibo SET liquidado = 1 
WHERE clave_recibo = (
    SELECT clave_recibo FROM recibo
    WHERE paciente_clave_paciente = (
        SELECT clave_paciente FROM paciente
        WHERE nombre_paciente = 'foo' AND 
        apellido_paterno_paciente = 'foo' AND
        apellido_materno_paciente = 'foo') 
    AND fecha_recibo = (
    SELECT fecha_recibo FROM recibo 
    WHERE paciente_clave_paciente = (
        SELECT clave_paciente FROM paciente
        WHERE nombre_paciente = 'foo' AND 
        apellido_paterno_paciente = 'foo' AND
        apellido_materno_paciente = 'foo')
    ORDER BY fecha_recibo DESC LIMIT 1) 
);
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> *Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'recibo' for update in FROM clause*

I've read that you can't modify the same table which you use in the FROM clause
Is there any alternative way to make this?

Answer (score 1):

dont know if it works ... join the table and then wirte your where statement

UPDATE `recibo` LEFT JOIN `recibo` r ON `recibo`.id = r.`id` SET ...  WHERE ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [temporary table](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20temporary%20table&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) from the inner select, then do the update as

where clave_recibo = (select clave_recibo from temptbl)

or with [join](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20update%20join&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari).

You should also probably [lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) the table for write, because someone might insert/update something after the temporary table creation and the update query.

Then you unlock and drop the temporary table.